# Creating an Android Attendace Monitoring application using biometrics that connected in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, android-fingerprint-api

we were looking for a proof if our project is possible to create..
our project is entitled "Android and Web Based attendance Monitoring with SMS Notification using Biometrics" 
The student will use the android phone version 6.0 - 6.0.1 for taking their fingerprint for attendance. after taking their fingerprint the data will be put inthe PHP MySQL to match the fingerprint if it is already registered and if it is registered message will appear on the screen in the android phone and say SUCCESSFUL.
The problem is no one make this so we cannot find any exact study for our project and we dont know if it is possible to do.

Comment: Yes This is possible.You just have to save fingerprint data to server and compare it with data sent from mobile.

Comment: can i use firebase as my server?

Comment: and can i use firebase as are database in php .

Comment: Yes.you can use firebase as your database .

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in India we are using this tech for unique identity verification called as  AADHAR so this is possible

Comment: actually, we wanted to use the fingerprint scanner of the phone. it is possible?